# What is C++ name lookup doing here? (& is GCC right?)

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

I was having a problem in some production code that I minimized to the following test case:

```
template<typename T>
void intermediate(T t)
{
    func(t); // line 4 ("func not declared in this scope")
}

namespace ns {
    struct type {};
}

void func(ns::type const & p); // line 11 ("declared here, later")

void foo(ns::type exit_node)
{
    intermediate(exit_node);  // line 15 ("required from here")
}
```

GCC 4.5 compiles this fine. Both with and without `-std=c++11`, 4.7 and 4.9 produce messages like:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void intermediate(T) [with T = ns::type]’:
test.cpp:15:27:   required from here
test.cpp:4:5: error: ‘func’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
test.cpp:11:6: note: ‘void func(const ns::type&)’ declared here, later in the translation unit
```

All of the following three things will cause the file to successfully compile:

1. Move `func(ns::type)` into the `ns` namespace (allowing ADL to find it in `ns`)
2. Move `type` into the global namespace (allowing ADL to find it in `::`)
3. Get rid of `intermediate` and call `func` directly from `foo`

So... what is going on here? Is it legal for GCC to reject this program? Why is `func` found by unqualified lookup in the third variant (call `func` directly from `foo`) but not found by unqualified lookup in the original variant at the point of instantiation?

Comment: Should it be: (&& is GCC right)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general rule is that anything that is not in the template definition context can only be picked up via ADL. In other words, normal unqualified lookup is performed only in the template definition context.

Since no declaration of `func` is visible when `intermediate` was defined, and `func` is not in a namespace associated with `ns::type`, the code is ill-formed.

Comment: So in other words, the candidate call targets is the union of (i) those found by unqualified lookup at the point of definition (hence the "defined later" note) and (ii) those found by ADL at the point of instantiation?

Comment: @EvanED ADL considers both the definition and the instantiation contexts.

Answer (score 3):

GCC is right. `func` can only be found via ADL since it is an unqualified, dependent function call. `func` is declared in the global namespace but that is *not* an associated namespace of `ns::type`, only `ns` is (which is why your current code fails). When you replace `intermediate(exit_node)` with a direct call to `func(exit_node)` inside `foo`, then it is found by normal unqualified lookup.